# Making a text appear under a button for half a second

Tags: c#, winforms, button, label

I want to make a button to perform some action and THEN let user know it was done. I tried making a label ander a button, then pause, then making it disappear.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // some action 
            label1.Text = "Done!";
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            label1.Text = "";
        }
```

But it doesn't work. What is my mistake?

Comment: How is it failing? What happens differently from what you expect?

Comment: @When I press a button, nothing happens. No text appears.

Answer (score 2):

As Grant says in his answer, you're blocking the UI thread. The simplest solution is to spawn a new `Task` which will do the update for you, thus releasing the UI thread.

The `Task` can simply use `Invoke` to push the update back to the UI thread after a `Sleep`.

In your case, this translates to something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // some action 
    label1.Text = "Done!";
    new TaskFactory().StartNew(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Invoke((Action)(() => label1.Text = string.Empty));
    });
}
```

Comment: @SergZ: You're most welcome. If you found the answer worked for you, please consider marking it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 1):

The call to `Thread.Sleep()` freezes the UI thread for a half-second, so that no updates to the UI can happen (including your update to the Label's text).

Here's a couple options:

- You could use a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_BackgroundWorker), which has built-in mechanisms for executing long-running code in a separate thread, and then updating the UI (such as your Label) when it's done.
- You could add a [`Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) to your `Form`, to perform the action and update the Label. Give it an interval of 500 (ms), and it'll wait roughly a half-second before firing.

Comment: I'd probably go for kicking off a `Task` using `TaskFactory`, passing in a short lambda function with just a `Sleep` followed by an `Invoke()` call to clear `label1`. Short and sweet.

Comment: If you want to merge my answer with yours, I'll happily delete mine. Would be best with your reasoning first. We'd get a better answer overall!

Comment: I'm not that rep-hungry - just like to see good fully formed answers. But then again this isn't exactly a ground-breaking situation, so I appreciate your sentiment! :)